# How does the count() method work?

Tags: python

I know that `str.count(sub)` return the number of occurrences of substring sub.
But I faced a strange problem that I cannot understand.
My code is as below:

```
str = 'helloworld'
print(str.count(''))
>>>11
```

The output is puzzling. Why does it return 11?
If `''` means any letters, why not return the length of it (10)?
I haven't found any answers about this.
Can anybody tell me about the implementation?

Comment: `''` doesn't mean any letters, it means an empty string. There are 11 empty strings in `'helloworld'`, one at the start, nine between each pair of letters and one at the end. If you want the length, use `len('helloworld')`.

Comment: A string starts with an empty string and also ends with one – so always one more than the number of characters.

Comment: Try looking at str.count.__doc__

Comment: Think of `"foo"` as being equal to `"" + "f" + "" + "o" + "" + "o" + ""`, which is in some sense the minimal number of empty strings to be found contained in the string `"foo"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`''` doesn't mean *any* string, it means *no* string (aka, the empty string, or the 0-length string). There are, strictly speaking, an infinite number of 0-length strings in a string, but practically, `len(string) + 1` is returned - one for just before first character, and one each for after every character.

This scenario has been explicitly special-cased in [`count.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/count.h#L16):

```
if (sub_len == 0)
    return (str_len < maxcount) ? str_len + 1 : maxcount;
```

When the search string is the empty string, `len(string) + 1` is returned by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @COLDSPEED, your explanation is really helpful.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Sorry to bother you again. When I looked into the implementation you mentioned above (count.h), there is one line I cannot understand (Line 14). if (str_len < 0) return 0;, why can str_len be less than 0?

Comment: @Yixin Without too much knowledge of python internals, it looks like that handles another invalid case when you call str.count with a "start" parameter (the index to begin searching from), and that start index is larger than the string's length. By default, start = 0.

Comment: You means the variable str_len here is actually not the length of original string? Maybe a value calculated by “start” parameter.

Comment: @Yixin I imagine it is calculated by whoever calls it. `str_len = len(str) - start`, and it is possible to go below 0 when start > len(str).

Comment: Got it. I have known more about the count() method, you really helps:-D

Comment: @Yixin The change was first made in [GitLab (SVN?) commit b51b470e](https://gitlab.merchise.org/merchise/cpython/commit/b51b470eb86ded7d3ea26081ca8bc89b4448f962). [The function is in fact called with `end - start` as `str_len`.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/09a9f1799c8c58f573c50cb2d526422436b8658b/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L9433)