# Why does "test".count('') return 5?

Tags: python, count

This is a short one, yet very irritating. I know I can count the amount of times a string occurs within another string like this:

```
'banana'.count('a')
>>>3
```

meaning that `banana` contains the letter `"a"` 3 times.

This is where it gets kind of weird.

My first confusion is - when I do `'foo'.count('')`, what does Python look for?

is `''` == None == anything?

It doesn't seem to be the case, but then again, what IS `''` logically speaking? And more importantly, why does

```
'test'.count('')
>>>5
```

return one more than the length of the string?

What the hell is included in a string that's always 1 higher than the amount of letters? the void?

EDIT: the `'` character twice looks like one `"` character. I am talking about two times `'` here, to avoid confusion

EDIT2: There seems to be some confusion about how the amount of `''` happen. Refer to comments below.

Comment: since `''.count('')` returns one im assuming that it literally searches for nothing.

Comment: It always returns len(string)+1, this is just a decision the developers took, you could make a case for other values (like infinity), there is a dupe somewhere

Comment: You could see s.count('') as counting the number of inter-letter spaces in the string, i.e. the ones used when parsing regexes.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49967934/4909087) for another explanation

Comment: @FlyingThunder please accept the other answer so I can freakin delete this -_-

Comment: What other answer?

Answer (score 27):

Every string<sup>1</sup> can be thought of as:

```
any_string = "" + "".join(any_string) + ""
```

which contains exactly `len(any_string) + 1` instances of `''`.

---

For `"foo"` for example, it would be:

```
"" + "f" + "" + "o" + "" + "o"+ ""
#    |----- from join -------|
```

As it can be seen there are `4` instances of `""` *in* it.

---

Note however, that this is a problem where **no** answer or **all** answers could somehow support a case for themselves. It get's philosophical:

- *How much nothing is contained in nothing?*
- *How much nothing is contained in something?*

This answer tries to explain the convention used by Python and does not intend to suggest that this is the way all languages do it \ should be doing it; **it is just how Python does it.**

---

<sup>1</sup>*Empty strings are an exception and are handled differently; they simply return `1`; which is yet another convention.*

Comment: Personally I don't think this logically follows entirely (although others might disagree), read the comments under this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192449/why-are-str-count-and-lenstr-giving-different-output/40192499#40192499 I agree with Sven who says "Infinitely often is just as valid an answer as string length plus one"

Comment: That makes sense, i was just keeping it because Qback suggested a different solution as far as i understood it, where count('') counts all letters and a possible "ending Null"

- edit:nevermind that, got deleted. alright, i guess that makes sense - i wasnt that far off with my "counting the void" idea then i guess 8)

Comment: @Chris_Rands You are right; it is a matter of convention. But it is the convention that is explained here; i'll try to make that clear(er).

Answer (score 7):

```
str.count(sub)
```

Counts the number of occurrences of `sub` in `str`.

Since strings are sequences, it basically counts the number of splits `sub` would cause in `str`.

An empty string is at the beginning, between each character, and at the end.

Hence, why when you use `'test'`, which has a `len` of 4, you get 5 occurrences of `sub` (`''`).