# How does the count function count?

Tags: python, string, function, count

```
strr = "string"
print(strr.count(""))
#output: 7
```

my only guess as a reason for that output is that the count("") function is counting the given string as
strr[0] = ",strr[1] = s, strr[2] = t, strr[3] = r, strr[4] = i, strr[5] = n, strr[6] = g, strr[7] = "
but that's a weird way to count
am I correct or is there some other reason why the output is 7?
usually, I would expect the output to be 6 
thanks for your answer in advance!

Comment: I don't think is a repeat question. I've looked for the answer but I couldn't find one

Comment: The other question (and its answers) are reachable by clicking the link at the beginning of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50235859/why-does-test-count-return-5

Comment: yes, I saw that later. Thx anyways 
!